Return email from RefreshToken journey in B2C CustomPolicy
We have a custom policy that we use to authenticate our users. We have two kind of users:

Users existing in the B2C tenant (invited guest users)
Shadow users in the tenant created via the signup_signin policy for users originating with AADCommon (known customers)

Our flow works in the following way:

Our web app (React) implements authentication with MSAL.JS towards the B2C-tenant.
If the user already has a session, use RefreshToken with login_hint
SelfAsserted-page with a single input (email) that is sent to a HRD-function
HRD(Home Realm Discovery)-function takes input (email) -> extracts domain value -> Lookup domain value towards an API to decide which IdP to use.
Send user to IdP (either OIDC to "itself" with guest users or AAD Common for known domains)
If AAD Common => Create "shadow" user in the B2C-tenant
Issue token with Claims

If we access the SignInSignUp-flow with &login_hint=email@domain.com we skip step 3, the SelfAsserted-page, and send the supplied login_hint to the HRD-function and continuing the next steps.
Initialise journey
Check if &login_hint=email is sent to the custom policy flow:
<ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>QueryParamClaims</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="InitialiseJourney">
                    <DisplayName>Initialise user journey claims</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.UserJourneyContextProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailLoginHint"
                            DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="IsLoginHintSentToJourney" />
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
    </ClaimsProviders>

IsLoginHintSentToJourney ClaimsTransformation:
<ClaimsTransformation Id="IsLoginHintSentToJourney"
                TransformationMethod="CompareClaimToValue">
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailLoginHint"
                        TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
                </InputClaims>
                <InputParameters>
                    <InputParameter Id="compareTo" DataType="string" Value="" />
                    <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="EQUAL" />
                    <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
                </InputParameters>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isLoginHintEmpty"
                        TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
                </OutputClaims>
            </ClaimsTransformation>

HRD Function:
<ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>REST APIs - HRD</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="HRD_Function">
                    <DisplayName>Do an IdP lookup based on email</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">
                            https://api-url.com/{email}</Item>
                        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
                        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
                        <Item Key="ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens">true</Item>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="Api-Key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_Key" />
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"
                            DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idpSelector"
                            PartnerClaimType="idpSelector" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInName" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

Self asserted page:
 <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>SelfAsserted</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EmailCollect">
                    <DisplayName>Email</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
                        Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <IncludeInSso>true</IncludeInSso>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}"
                            AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

RefreshToken Claims Transformation:
<ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Refresh token journey</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="RefreshTokenReadAndSetup">
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <!-- To get the Azure AD refresh token claim from the Azure AD B2C refresh
                        token, we added the oauth2Refresh_token output claim.
                       Check the extension policy for more details and the full technical profile implementation -->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="oauth2Refresh_token" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IsAzureAd" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idp_oid" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="idpSelector" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>

UserJourney:
<UserJourney Id="HRD_SignIn">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="InitialiseJourney"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="InitialiseJourney" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>isLoginHintEmpty</Value>
                            <Value>true</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="pre-hrd"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EmailCollect" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="HRD" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="HRD_Function" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange"
                    ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>idpSelector</Value>
                            <Value>OpenIDConnect</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADOIDC"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADB2C-OpenIdConnect" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange"
                    ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>idpSelector</Value>
                            <Value>Common</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADCommon"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AADCommon-Oauth" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>idpSelector</Value>
                            <Value>OpenIDConnect</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>objectId</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>idpSelector</Value>
                            <Value>OpenIDConnect</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="SendClaims"
                    CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
        </UserJourney>

RefreshToken Journey:
<UserJourney Id="RedeemRefreshTokenWithAADCommonToken">
            <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <!-- Read the claims from the refresh token -->
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="RefreshTokenSetupExchange"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="RefreshTokenReadAndSetup" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- You can add a step that fetch data from a REST API here-->

                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <!-- Read the user profile from the directory and assert the refresh token
                        date is valid.
                       This steps prevents having a stale data in the return access token-->
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckRefreshTokenDateFromAadExchange"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- Refresh the Azure AD token-->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                            <Value>IsAzureAd</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="REST-RefreshAADAccessToken"
                            TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-RefreshAADAccessToken" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>

                <!-- You can add a step that fetch data from a REST API here-->

                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims"
                    CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
        </UserJourney>

Our problem
So far everything looks to be working, but when we refresh our accessToken with the refreshToken the value of email is set to "email":"{OIDC:LoginHint}".
So the first refresh of the AccessToken works and the original AccessToken contains the correct email for the user, but after the login_hint is being set to the value "{OIDC:LoginHint}" - the next refresh of the accessToken breaks with the error: AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.
If we clear local + session storage and cookies and try again, it will work for the first tries and then fail on the third with the same symptom as described above. So the reproduction of the error is consistent.
We have tried setting DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" and/or "AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"" in the OutputClaims-section of "RefreshToken Claims Transformation" with no effect.
I am pretty sure that it's just one minor thing we are missing in our flow, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what/where that is.

Ensure that the email claim is being correctly set and resolved in the RefreshTokenReadAndSetup technical profile.
